# Enable mod_rewrite On Shared Hosting Apache Server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have made some changes to a clients website.
The client was continually being attacked using SQL injection, and at the moment the URL contains variables that the website needs (i.e. index.php?filenmae=home.php).

So after securing the site as best I could using `mysql_real_escape_strings` and `stripslashes`, I then came to do URL rewriting in Apache.

At the moment, the server the website is currently on doesn't support mod_rewrite (i've checked using phpinfo) and it's not a server belonging to us. Is there anything I can do in my .htaccess file that would enable mod_rewrite for this website?

Comment: I think this question belongs on serverfault.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mick, the best solution for you is to change your code.  I'm guessing that in your code you then include the filename specified, e.g.

```
include $_GET['filename'];
```

In short, there is *no way* using `mod_rewrite` that you can make this secure.

However, you can make it more secure very easily by checking that the filename is valid, e.g.

```
$valid_filenames = array('home.php', 'foo.php', 'bar.php', /* etc... */);
if (!in_array($_GET['filename'], $valid_filenames)) {
    echo "Invalid request.";
    exit;
}
include $_GET['filename'];
```

Just make sure that you *validate* the requested filename *before* including it and you'll be much better off.

Comment: Hey cheers for the reply. I've spoken to the hosting company and they have said they can do URL rewriting but they use Zeus(?) instead. So I have to find out how to perform URL rewriting in that now. Also, I have taken your comment and I am currently in the process of implementing it. Thank you :)

Comment: I implemented the code in to this code, but have been told that the user can't be restricted in adding pages. At the moment we're going to release it using the mysql_escape_string functions and without mod_rewrite. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

If mod_rewrite is installed, you can configure it in your local `.htaccess` file.

- Create a file called `.htaccess` in your site's root folder.
- First line should be `RewriteEngine On`.
- Second line should be `RewriteBase /`.
- After that, put in your rewrite rules are required.

If it isn't installed, you're out of luck - no web host will install extra software on a shared hosting box just for one client.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot dynamically load mod_rewrite. Most hosting providers have mod_rewrite enabled on Apache servers. If they do not, you could ask them for enabling it. Otherwise, if you really need mod_rewrite, consider switching hosting providers.

As an alternative, you can rewrite URL's in PHP.

1. `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` can be used for getting the part after the question mark (*http://example.com/file.php?**this_part***).
2. Split it by your preferred parameter separator (e.g. `/`, `;`) using `explode('/', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])`
3. Loop through the values, and split those using a preferred value separator (e.g. '=', ':')
4. Overwrite `$_GET` with an empty array, and put the newly generated values in it.
   Note: `filter_input` and related functions do not operate on `$_GET`. Thus, this method will *not* work for `filter_input`.

Comment: Moving providers isn't an option unfortunately. I will e-mail them now and ask them about it.

Comment: Also, am I doing the right thing by using mod_rewrite to prevent against sql injections?

Comment: No. If you see mod_rewrite as a secure solution for preventing SQL injections, you're completely wrong. To prevent SQL injection, always use proper escaping or prepared statements.

Comment: But doesn't mod_rewrite help prevent it even a small bit? I have included mysql_escape_string in the code as well. I'm trying to lock the whole thing down.

Comment: No, it does not help. Using mod_rewrite could catch common scans by bots, but it will not make your application more secure. "I've included mysql_escape_string in the code": `/*mysql_escape_string*/`. Yep, I've now included it too. `mysql_escape_string` is deprecated in favor of `mysql_real_escape_string`. It's all about implementation.

Answer (score 0):

For Shared Hosting Server , It Really Work.

- Create a file called `.htaccess` in your site's root folder.
- First line should be `RewriteEngine On`.
- Second line should be `RewriteBase /`.
- After that, put in your rewrite rules are required.