# How enable mod_rewrite without editing httpd.conf file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel-5, config

I am working in a Laravel project. I enabled mod_rewrite module from the httpd.conf file. I go to apache -> conf-> httpd.conf and uncommented the #LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so this and mod_rewrite module was enabled successfully. I checked it using phpinfo function.

Now I uploaded the same project to live server .but I don’t have permissions to enter in conf folder. So cannot edit httpd.conf file to enable mod_rewrite module. How can I enable mod_rewrite module using php.ini or htaccess file or using some php coding?

Please help me

Comment: Please check it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410992/enable-mod-rewrite-on-shared-hosting-apache-server

Comment: Ask your Hosting company to enable it for you ,otherwise no way